# Reducibility of a polynomial $f(x)$ in a polynomial ring $\Bbb{R}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Given $f(x)$ in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{R}[x]$ proof the following statements:

1. $f(x)$ is irreducible iff $deg(f(x)) = 1$
2. $f(x)$ is irreducible iff $deg(f(x)) = 2$ and $f(x)$ has no roots.

For 1. I tried the following:

If $deg(f(x)) = 1$ then $f(x) = ax+b$. Therefore, there is no possible factorization of $f(x)$ such that $(cx+d)(ex+f) = ax+b$. Because, $deg((cx+d)(ex+f)) = 2$.

Now, with 2. I did a similar procedure:

If $deg(f(x)) = 2$ then $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. By hypothesis, $f(x)$ has no roots, therefore there is no possible factorization of $f(x)$ such that $(cx+d)(ex+f) = ax^2+bx+c$.

In the case of 2. I feel like I can't conclude. It would be helpful if you corrected my proofs or if they are wrong, give me a hint of where to go. Thanks.

Comment: For $1$, the reasoning is not correct, at least without further verification. Why are you multiplying degree $1$ polynomials? Instead, I'd argue that if two polynomials multiply to a linear polynomial, one must be a constant since two polynomials have a product of degree $2$ or higher.

Comment: For $2$, note that a quadratic, if reducible, is the product of linear polynomials. But that means that it has $2$ roots.

Comment: Key is $\,\deg(fg) = \deg f + \deg g.\,$ You should *prove* that and *explicitly* cite that *every* time you (implicitly?) employ it to convince the reader that your reasoning is well-founded.

Comment: Thanks, so in 2. I can do it by contraposition and that would be enough, right? But I'm still thinking about 1. The case of the constant might help. I also thought, for example, in the case of $f(x) = 3x = (6x^{-2})(\frac{1}{3}x^3)$. I can't find a nice way to even start the proof.

Comment: Both statements are wrong. You should replace this with a single statement : $f$ is irreducible iff either $deg(f)=1$ or ($deg(f)=2$ and $f$ has no roots).